# Issue in Binding in Windows Phone 8 app based on MVVM

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

This is my first windows8 application which is very much based on the default template provided by the Visual studio. The issue is when i try to assign the Items property value by creating new instance of Observable collection in LoadData() the data are not bound ,but when i add items to the list using Items.Add    method i can see the data in the UI. I hope some can explain me about the behavior and if i am missing anything very obvious.

```
namespace Sample.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
           this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();                    
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A collection for ItemViewModel objects.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

        private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";

        /// <summary>
        /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view 
        /// to display its value using a Binding
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string SampleProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _sampleProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _sampleProperty)
                {
                    _sampleProperty = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sample property that returns a localized string
        /// </summary>
        public string LocalizedSampleProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return AppResources.SampleProperty;
            }
        }

        public bool IsDataLoaded
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items collection.
        /// </summary>
        public void LoadData()
        {

            try
            {
                using (IQContext context = new IQContext("isostore:/Test.sdf"))
                {
                    var query = (from c in context.Categories

                                 select new ItemViewModel
                                 {
                                     CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                                     CategoryName = c.CategoryName

                                 });

                    // Items present in the list.
                    this.Items = 
                        new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(query);

                    // this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() 
                    //     { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName = "Rishi"}); // This Works

                    this.IsDataLoaded = true;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Items` property should implement INPC because you are changing the reference in `LoadData` and the UI needs to be notified:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
```

to

```
private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items;
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items 
{ 
    get
    {
        return this.items;
    }

    private set
    {
        this.items = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: ObservableCollection has an event, CollectionChanged, which some standard views (ListBox, LongListSelector etc) subscribe to so they can do incremental updates. When you change the reference, there is no way subscribed listeners can know that-- so you have to NotifyProperyChanged, (after which the views will drop their old CollectionChanged listener and add one for the new collection.)